# Is there a simple way to one-time trigger an Intent in Dialogflow ES?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I only wanted to trigger certain intents once, say to stop a chatbot sound from repeatedly firing.

Is there a simple way to do this using outputs?

I've tried setting the output to 0 OR 1 but it didn't work. Is there another workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly sure about a simple way, but you can review these documents to better understand the functions that need to be considered for this use case.

- [Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/events-overview)

> Intents are normally matched when an end-user expression matches an intent training phrase. However, you can also trigger intents using events. Events can be invoked in many ways.

- [Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-overview)

> Events: With events, you can invoke an intent based on something that has happened, instead of what an end-user communicates.

Here's another resource that you may find useful

- [Detect intent with audio output](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-tts#detect-intent-tts-python)